# I need a sample of python unit testing sqlalchemy model with nose

Tags: python, unit-testing, testing, sqlalchemy, nose

Can someone show me how to write unit tests for sqlalchemy model I created using nose.

I just need one simple example.

Thanks.

Comment: Be more specific: do you need help in how to setup nose? or how to test a model?

Answer (score 38):

You can simply create an in-memory SQLite database and bind your session to that.

Example:

```
from db import session # probably a contextbound sessionmaker
from db import model

from sqlalchemy import create_engine

def setup():
    engine = create_engine('sqlite:///:memory:')
    session.configure(bind=engine)
    # You probably need to create some tables and 
    # load some test data, do so here.

    # To create tables, you typically do:
    model.metadata.create_all(engine)

def teardown():
    session.remove()


def test_something():
    instances = session.query(model.SomeObj).all()
    eq_(0, len(instances))
    session.add(model.SomeObj())
    session.flush()
    # ...
```

Comment: Great answer! I think you need to call `create_all` on the MetaData object to actually create tables. Also if db-vendor specific data types are used, then some of the DDLs may not run.

Comment: Good points. I updated the example to show a call to create_all.

Comment: This is a horrible answer if SQLLite is not your production database. Never test with a different database than the one you are using in production. They will have lots of differences and you are setting yourself up for a disaster.

Comment: You could of course use a Postgresql, MySQL, etc. database server for executing the tests against. The setup and teardown methods above would possibly be a bit different then, you probably would do a CREATE DATABASE in setup and a DROP DATABASE in teardown.

I have seldom had any problems by switching DB backends using SQLAlchemy. I routinely do automatic tests against SQLite and run the prod system on Postg, MySQL or MSSQL.

One system I developed, we did unit testing against SQLite, integration testing on Linux/Postgres and the production system was Win/MSSQL. No changes in DB access code.

Answer (score 2):

Check out the [fixture](http://code.google.com/p/fixture/) project. We used nose to test that and it's also a way to declaratively define data to test against, there will be some extensive examples for you to use there!

See also [fixture documentation](http://farmdev.com/projects/fixture/).