# Writting py test for sqlalchemy app

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, pytest

I am trying convert unit test into py test. I am using the unit test example

```
class TestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        app.config['TESTING'] = True
        app.config['CSRF_ENABLED'] = False
        app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///' + os.path.join(basedir, 
        'test.db')
        db.create_all()

    def tearDown(self):
        db.session.remove()
        db.drop_all()
```

I am not sure, What should be its py test version.

Answer (score 19):

I searched high and low for a well explained solution to use SqlAlchemy ***without*** Flask-SQLAlchemy and run tests with Pytest, so here's how i have achieved this:

1. Set up your `engine` & `Session` objects as per the docs. (I have opted for sessionmaker as i want to check in my app if the session is still available in the Flask's request thread pool, see: https://dev.to/nestedsoftware/flask-and-sqlalchemy-without-the-flask-sqlalchemy-extension-3cf8
2. Import your `Base` object from wherever you've created it in your app. This will create all the tables in your database defined by the `engine`.
3. Now we want to Yield a `Session` back to your unit tests. The idea is to setup before calling `Yield` & teardown after. Now, in your test you can create a table and populate it with some rows of data etc.
4. Now we must close the Session, this is important!
5. Now by calling `Base.metadata.drop_all(bind=engine)` we drop all the tables in the database ( we can define a table(s) to drop if required, default is: `tables=None`)

   ```
    engine = create_engine(create_db_connection_str(config), echo=True)
    Session = scoped_session(sessionmaker(bind=engine))

    @pytest.fixture(scope="function") # or "module" (to teardown at a module level)
    def db_session():
        Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
        session = Session()
        yield session
        session.close()
        Base.metadata.drop_all(bind=engine)
   ```
6. Now we can pass the function scoped fixture to each unit test:

   ```
    class TestNotebookManager:
        """
            Using book1.mon for this test suite
        """
        book_name = "book1"

        def test_load(self, client: FlaskClient, db_session) -> None:
            notebook = Notebook(name=self.book_name)
            db_session.add(book)
            db_session.commit()
            rv = client.get(f"/api/v1/manager/load?name={self.name}")
            assert "200" in rv.status
   ```

Comment: would it make sense to have `yield Session()` instead?

Comment: @AntoineViscardi thanks for the correction, in fact it would make more sense, as scoped_session returns a factory object that I haven't instanciated

Comment: With this fixture having the scope of `function`, it seems that it would `create_all` and `drop_all` for each unit test. So for an example where multiple user features are tested in their own unit test functions, (i.e. `test_follow_user`, or `test_report_user`) would it need to also need to take the steps necessary to re-populate the users into the database during each unit test as this `db_session` fixture is only function scope? Would it be better to set the `db_session` to a module or class scope for this so that it doesn't have to recreate the database for each unit test?

Comment: @ppak10 A great question but I think that is a political decision outside the scope of this technical solution. I have updated the answer with your scope options, thank you!

Comment: A similar option is to separate the table creation from the session as shown here: https://gist.github.com/kissgyorgy/e2365f25a213de44b9a2.

Answer (score 1):

First off, py.test should just run the existing unittest test case.  However the native thing to do in py.test is use a fixture for the setup and teardown:

```
import pytest

@pytest.fixture
def some_db(request):
    app.config['TESTING'] = True
    app.config['CSRF_ENABLED'] = False
    app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///' + os.path.join(basedir, 'test.db')
    db.create_all()
    def fin():
        db.session.remove()
        db.drop_all()
    request.addfinalizer(fin)

def test_foo(some_db):
    pass
```

Note that I have no idea about SQLAlchemy and whether there are better ways of handling it's setup and teardown.  All this example demonstrates is how to turn the setup/teardown methods into a fixture.

Comment: I am getting  AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'config' at app.config['TESTING'] = True. It worked if I use unittest instead of py.test

Comment: I already know what you explained above. My problem is pytest is not recognizing config, so how can I give db url?

Comment: The error message means that “app” is a function, while you seem to expect it’s something else (an instance of the Flask class I guess).  What is app?  Why isn’t it what you expect?